# Numerical calculation of Integral of Si(x)/x

Tags: quadrature

I'm interested in evaluating

\begin{equation}
\int_0^x \frac{Si(t)}{t}\;dt
\end{equation}

Where

\begin{equation}
Si(x) = \int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t}\;dt
\end{equation}

I've found a nice method for evaluating $Si(x)$ using Pade and Chebyshev-Pade approximations in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.7676.pdf but I'm unable to find an existing equivalent method of the integral above.

I can probably derive the small $x$ Pade approximation without too much difficulty, as the integral has a relatively simple Taylor series expansion, but I'm unsure how to approach the large $x$  part.

Does anyone have a reference for calculatin such an integral?
Or even a good reference for deriving the large $x$ Chebyshev-Pade approximation for a similar integral?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/32790/numerical-evaluation-of-highly-oscillatory-integral) question and answer? I think your integral falls into the same category, especially the second answer.

Comment: @Bort That's a neat answer, but I think its geared towards infinite integrals, rather than definite integrals. If you can see a way to adapt it to this case, I'd love a pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For large $x$, you can use the same approach as the one in the paper
you cite. They define these *auxiliary* functions that link
$\mathrm{Si},\mathrm{Ci}$ with $\sin,\cos$, and the point of why this
works is that the relationship between these two pairs of functions is
in general a $2\times 2$ matrix, but this matrix only has two
independent functions in its components.

Using Mathematica ([code
gist](https://gist.github.com/ikirill/2ec0ebb547059312b4d680c4a7895fbb)),
I computed the same auxiliary functions for your case. The integral
you give is
$$ \mathrm{Si}(x)\log x - \int_0^x t^{-1}\sin t\log t\,\mathrm{d}t. $$
Consider the four integrals
$$ \int_x^\infty t^{-1}\big( 
\sin t, \cos t, \sin t\log t, \cos t\log t
\big)\,\mathrm{d}t. 
$$
These are equal to
$$
\begin{gathered}
f_1 \cos x + f_2\sin x,\\
f_2\cos x - f_1\sin x,\\
-f_3\cos x+f_1\cos x\log x+f_4\sin x+f_2\sin x\log x,\\
-f_4\cos x+f_2\cos x\log x-f_3\sin x-f_1\sin x\log x.
\end{gathered}
$$
To compute this, I applied integration by parts to each integral up to order $O(x^{-10})$, and then read off the coefficients of $(\cos x,\sin x,\cos x\log x,\sin x\log x)$, which are the auxiliary functions. The power series for them are:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_1 &= \frac{1}{x} - \frac{2}{x^3} + \frac{24}{x^5} - \frac{720}{x^7} +
\frac{40320}{x^9}+\cdots,\\
f_2 &= \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{6}{x^4} + \frac{120}{x^6} -
\frac{5040}{x^8} + \frac{362880}{x^{10}} - \cdots,\\
f_3 &= \frac{3}{x^3} - \frac{50}{x^5} + \frac{1764}{x^7} -
\frac{109584}{x^9}+\cdots,\\
f_4 &= \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{11}{x^4} + \frac{274}{x^6} -
\frac{13068}{x^8} + \frac{1026576}{x^{10}}-\cdots.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here $f_1,f_2$ should be equal to $f,g$ in the paper. To find closed forms for $f_{3,4}$, they are the $(\Im,-\Re)$ parts of the integral
$$ \int_x^\infty t^{-1}\log(t/x)e^{\mathrm{i}(t-x)}\,\mathrm{d}t, $$
change the contour of integration to $(x,x+\mathrm{i}\infty)$ and use $t=x(1+\mathrm{i}v)$. Then
$$
f_3 = \int_0^\infty \frac{\frac12 \log(1+v^2) + v\arctan v}{1+v^2}e^{-v x}\,\mathrm{d}v,\\
f_4 = \int_0^\infty \frac{-\frac12 v \log(1+v^2) + \arctan v}{1+v^2}e^{-v x}\,\mathrm{d}v,
$$
which are easy to evaluate numerically.

Because there is a one-to-one mapping between the $f$'s and the four
integrals (a system of four linear equations in $f$'s for each value of $x$), this is enough information to numerically compute the Pade
approximations of the auxiliary functions $f_{1,2,3,4}$ just like they
do in the paper.

Comment: Since you are using Mathematica, don't you think it's a little weird that, in Mathematica, `Integrate[SinIntegral[z]/z, {z, 0, a}]` shows an exact result in terms of `HypergeometricPFQ`?

Comment: Worth noting the coefficients of `f1`, `f2` are just pulled alternatively from `n!`, and those for f3,f4 look like they come from https://oeis.org/A000254, which can be generated by : $a_{n+1} =(n+1)*a_n+n!$.

Comment: @David From a numerical perspective there's a problem with using hypergeometric functions. It is a very general class of functions, encompassing pretty much all the standard ones (https://dlmf.nist.gov/15), and as a result it is very hard to compute accurately, requiring a combination of different approaches chosen depending on the argument and the parameters (https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.19;  http://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/hypergeometric.html). $\mathrm{Si}(x)$ can also be expressed terms of hypergeometrics (https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.11), but it's computed as in https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.18.